# How to get callback data from nodejs module exports function

Tags: node.js

i can not get data from callback function at nodejs. data is undefined..

```
const fs = require('fs');
module.exports.license = fs.readFile('license.json', (err,data) => {
if(err){
  return err;
} else { return data; }
});

const boot = require('./boot');
console.log(boot.license);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code needs to be changed a little bit if you want it to work:

```
const fs = require('fs');

module.exports.license = function license(cb) {
  fs.readFile("license.json", cb);
}
```

Now in your main module, you will use it as follows:

```
const boot = require('./boot');

boot.license((err, data) => {
  if (err) console.err(err);
  console.log(data);
});
```

The idea is that you will need to pass the callback as function parameter where you will get the data or the error; A decent article on [Callbacks explained in plain english](https://www.alxolr.com/articles/callbacks-explained-in-plain-english).